# How to understand the DICOM tag 0040,db73 ? How to validate if the values are correct?

Tags: image, image-processing, dicom

I am working on one of the issue with the SR. The issue is happening with the values of the dicom tag 0040,db73 (referenced content identifier). Tried to understand from the standard document but did not get much details. How to validate if the value of this tag is correct or not? Is there a way to figure out if there is any issue with tag value

[image: DICOM tag 0040,db73]

Answer (score 0):

See the note here

https://books.google.com/books?id=EVjOolUJNGUC&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=dicom+referenced+content+identifier&source=bl&ots=VmDpmAdvjt&sig=FSySQbqKXDCxTaJZkRMxM9i_HXA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizkr7X7rjJAhWWnYgKHTf3CqMQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=dicom%20referenced%20content%20identifier&f=false

Not too helpful, but it seems there's a format issue you can check. Apart from that, you don't seem to have access to the referring source or am I missing that?

Comment: Thank you John. i did go through the pdf and few other resources. But what i m thinking is is there a way i can figure out whether the values are valid/in order or not for the tag 0040,db73.